# Can't fix "There is no Action mapped for namespace [/build/result] ". What is the correct way of adding action to bamboo namespace?

Tags: struts2, struts, bamboo, struts-config, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I am developing a bamboo plugin using the Atlassian-SDK. This plugin would add a new **tab** to the Bamboo Jobs page that would display an HTML report (present in artifact) in the same **tab**.

My Atlassian-plugin.xml looks like

```
<xwork key="viewRobotReport" name="View Robot Report">
    <package name="RobotPlugin" extends="buildResultView">
    <action name="viewRobotReport" class="robot.RobotReport">
    <result name="success" type="freemarker">viewRobotReport.ftl</result>
    </action>
    </package>
</xwork>

<web-item key="RobotJob-${planKey}-${buildNumber}" name="RobotReport" section="results.subMenu/results" weight="80">
    <label key="Robot Report"/>
    <link linkId="RobotBuild-${planKey}-${buildNumber}">/build/result/viewRobotReport.action?buildKey=${planKey}&amp;buildNumber=${buildNumber}
    </link>
    <condition class="robot.RobotReportViewCondition"/>
</web-item>
```

I am extending my class RobotReport from ViewBuildResults so that I can fetch the artifact details.

After I click on the tab I get an error

> ```
> Apologies, this page could not be properly decorated (data is missing)
> ```
>
> The URL for the page is 
>   172.xx.x.x0:6990/bamboo/build/result/viewRobotReport.action?buildKey=TPRO1-TPLAN1-JOB1&buildNumber=1

From the logs I can see the below errors

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2018-05-02 13:41:48,724 INFO [http-nio-6990-exec-12] [AccessLogFilter] admin GET http://172.20.1.30:6990/bamboo/build/result/viewRobotReport.action?buildKey=TPRO1-TPLAN1-JOB1&buildNumber=1&_=1525264904397 177957kb
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2018-05-02 13:41:48,725 ERROR [http-nio-6990-exec-12] [BambooStrutsUnknownHandler] There is no Action mapped for namespace [/build/result] and action name [viewRobotReport] associated with context path [/bamboo].
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2018-05-02 13:41:48,788 INFO [http-nio-6990-exec-9] [AccessLogFilter] admin GET http://172.20.1.30:6990/bamboo/build/result/viewRobotReport.action?buildKey=TPRO1-TPLAN1-JOB1&buildNumber=1 76808kb
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2018-05-02 13:41:48,789 ERROR [http-nio-6990-exec-9] [BambooStrutsUnknownHandler] There is no Action mapped for namespace [/build/result] and action name [viewRobotReport] associated with context path [/bamboo].
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2018-05-02 13:41:48,819 ERROR [http-nio-6990-exec-9] [runtime] Error executing FreeMarker template
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] FreeMarker template error:
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] The following has evaluated to null or missing:
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] ==> navigationContext  [in template "decorators/resultDecorator.ftl" at line 17, column 18]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]
```

I understand that BambooStruts cannot find action in the namespace ***/build/result*** in ***/bamboo***.

My freemarker template contains only this bit.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="decorator" content="result"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

What is the correct way of adding action (viewRobotReport) in bamboo's /build/result namespace?

Bamboo Developer Forums doesn't have a guideline for implementing this. 
Somewhere it mentions "setter injection" but not sure what that is.

Any tiny hint would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can see that the struts.xml does not contain the below package definition
`<package name="RobotPlugin" extends="buildResultView">
    <action name="viewRobotReport" class="robot.RobotReport">
      <result name="success" type="freemarker">viewRobotReport.ftl</result>
    </action>
    </package>`
Shouldn't the struts.xml be updated automatically by bamboo ?

Answer (score 0):

I found what the problem was when I was looking at all the logs of **atlas-run**.
I could the the below in the logs..

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2018-05-03 13:30:07,737 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] [BambooPluginUtils] A problem has occurred when instantiating action class [robot.RobotReport], skipping action [viewRobotReport]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'robot.RobotReport': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.atlassian.bamboo.storage.StorageLocationService com.atlassian.bamboo.build.ViewBuildResults.storageLocationService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.atlassian.bamboo.storage.StorageLocationService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I fixed it in the code by doing the below..

```
import com.atlassian.plugin.spring.scanner.annotation.imports.ComponentImport;
import com.atlassian.plugin.spring.scanner.annotation.component.Scanned;

@Scanned
public class RobotReport extends ViewBuildResults {

    public RobotReport(@ComponentImport StorageLocationService storageLocationService){
```

Useful link

https://community.developer.atlassian.com/t/spring-autowiring-issues-when-extending-viewbuildresults/14766/2